# Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null with Springboot and Tomacat

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, sockjs, stompjs

The following is the error I'm getting in the server logs.

`04:42:53.259 [41] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler - Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null`

I have gone through almost all questions out there regarding the similar issue but none seems to solve the issue. For me the issue is occurring intermittently, not every requests fails. There is also no proxy involved.

The application is deployed in kubernetes. Is there any other reason other that proxies that this issue can occur?